# Using multiple filters on Map and process each filter differently using Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of Subscription. Subscription is the class with properties Frequency and the amount.My goal is to get TOTALACCRUEDMONTHLYAMOUNT, so I approached it in two steps 1) By grouping the Subscriptions by Frequency, and 2)convert the amounts of Frequency types Quarterly, Semi-annually and Annually to Monthly.

For Example:

```
Subscriptions [{
 subscription {
 frequency: Annually,
 amount    : 1200
 },
 subscription {
 frequency: Annually,
 amount    : 1200
 },
 subscription {
 frequency: Quarterly,
 amount    : 400
 },
 subscription {
 frequency: Quarterly,
 amount    : 400
 },
 subscription {
 frequency: Monthly,
 amount    : 100
 },
 subscription {
 frequency: Semi Annually,
 amount    : 600
 },
 subscription {
 frequency: Semi Annually,
 amount    : 600
 }
 }]
```

I was able to group by using the below logic

```
Map<String,BigDecimal> amountByFrequency = subscriptions.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
               subscription::getFrequency,
                   Collectors.mapping(
                   Subscription::getAmount,
                       Collectors.reducing(
                         BigDecimal.ZERO,
                             (total,elm) ->(total.add(elm))))));
```

so that I could get the Map as below now

```
{[Monthly, 100],[Quarterly, 800],[Annually, 2400 ],[Semi Annually, 1200]}
```

However, still converting the amounts to monthly amounts is not done yet, so I achieved that using the below switch statement.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal> entry : amountByFrequency.entrySet()) {

        switch(entry.getKey()) {
        case "Monthly":
            sum = sum.add(entry.getValue());
            break;
        case "Quaterly":
            sum = sum.add(entry.getValue().divide(new BigDecimal("4"),2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            break;
        case "Semiannually":
            sum = sum.add(entry.getValue().divide(new BigDecimal("6"),2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            break;
        case "Yearly":
        case "Annually":
            sum = sum.add(entry.getValue().divide(new BigDecimal("12"),2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            break;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to replace the above code with Stream API??
The whole main class is below.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Subscription> subscriptions = getSubscriptionsList();
    BigDecimal sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;

   //Group by frequency.
    Map<String, BigDecimal> amountByFrequency = subscriptions.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Subscription::getFrequency,     Collectors.mapping(Subscription::getAmount,
                    Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, (total, elm) ->   (total.add(elm))))));

  //convert amount to monthly
       for (Map.Entry<String, BigDecimal> entry :       amountByFrequency.entrySet()) {

        switch (entry.getKey()) {
        case "Monthly":
            sum = sum.add(entry.getValue());
            break;
        case "Quaterly": // divide by 4, to convert to Monthly
            sum = sum.add(entry.getValue().divide(new BigDecimal("4"), 2,    RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            break;
        case "Semiannually": // divide by 6, to convert to Monthly
            sum = sum.add(entry.getValue().divide(new BigDecimal("6"), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            break;
        case "Yearly":
        case "Annually":  // divide by 12, to convert to Monthly
            sum = sum.add(entry.getValue().divide(new BigDecimal("12"), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("java 8--" + sum); //  accrued total subscription     amount

}

static class Subscription {
    private String frequency;

    private BigDecimal amount;

    public String getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(String frequency) {
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

}


//build dummy subscription list.
public static List<Subscription> getSubscriptionsList() {

    List<Subscription> SubscriptionsList = new ArrayList<>();

    Subscription SubscriptionMonthly1 = new Subscription();
    SubscriptionMonthly1.setFrequency("Monthly");
    SubscriptionMonthly1.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1000.00));

    Subscription SubscriptionMonthly2 = new Subscription();
    SubscriptionMonthly2.setFrequency("Monthly");
    SubscriptionMonthly2.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1000.00));

    Subscription SubscriptionQuaterly1 = new Subscription();
    SubscriptionQuaterly1.setFrequency("Quaterly");
    SubscriptionQuaterly1.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1000.00));

    Subscription SubscriptionQuaterly2 = new Subscription();
    SubscriptionQuaterly2.setFrequency("Quaterly");
    SubscriptionQuaterly2.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1000.00));

    Subscription SubscriptionSemiannually1 = new Subscription();
    SubscriptionSemiannually1.setFrequency("Semiannually");
    SubscriptionSemiannually1.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1000.00));

    Subscription SubscriptionSemiannually2 = new Subscription();
    SubscriptionSemiannually2.setFrequency("Semiannually");
    SubscriptionSemiannually2.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1000.00));

    Subscription SubscriptionYearly1 = new Subscription();
    SubscriptionYearly1.setFrequency("Yearly");
    SubscriptionYearly1.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1000.00));

    Subscription SubscriptionYearly2 = new Subscription();
    SubscriptionYearly2.setFrequency("Yearly");
    SubscriptionYearly2.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1000.00));

    Subscription SubscriptionAnnually1 = new Subscription();
    SubscriptionAnnually1.setFrequency("Annually");
    SubscriptionAnnually1.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1000.00));

    Subscription SubscriptionAnnually2 = new Subscription();
    SubscriptionAnnually2.setFrequency("Annually");
    SubscriptionAnnually2.setAmount(new BigDecimal(1000.00));

    SubscriptionsList.add(SubscriptionMonthly1);
    SubscriptionsList.add(SubscriptionMonthly2);
    SubscriptionsList.add(SubscriptionQuaterly1);
    SubscriptionsList.add(SubscriptionQuaterly2);
    SubscriptionsList.add(SubscriptionSemiannually1);
    SubscriptionsList.add(SubscriptionSemiannually2);
    SubscriptionsList.add(SubscriptionYearly1);
    SubscriptionsList.add(SubscriptionYearly2);
    SubscriptionsList.add(SubscriptionAnnually1);
    SubscriptionsList.add(SubscriptionAnnually2);

    return SubscriptionsList;

}
```

}

Comment: You should probably make a separate method for the logic that normalizes subscription amount.  Perhaps add `getMonthlyAmount()` method to `Subscription`  class where it can be properly tested and maintained.  Then replace `Subscription::getAmount` with `Subscription::getMonthlyAmount` in your stream expression.

Comment: you are probably not going to get a lot of attention here... at least format the code and provide the examples so that other people could simply copy/paste in their IDE and run...

Comment: @Misha Subscription class is derived from Schema, can only read data from that class. Thanks for the suggesion Eugene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something along those lines :

```
private static Map<String,Double> frequencyFactor = new HashMap<>();
frequencyFactor.add("Monthly", 1);
frequencyFactor.add("Annualy", 1.0/12);
frequencyFactor.add("Yearly", 1.0/12);
frequencyFactor.add("Quaterly", 1.0/4);
frequencyFactor.add("Semiannually", 1.0/6);

Integer sum = subs.stream()
                  .mapToDouble(sub -> sub.getAmount() * frequencyFactor.get(sub.getFrequency()))
                  .sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

With the advice from Aaron, I was able to replace the switch statement with the below lines using streams.

```
Map<String,BigDecimal> frequencyFactor = new HashMap<>();
frequencyFactor.put("Monthly", new BigDecimal(1.0));
frequencyFactor.put("Annually", new BigDecimal(1.0/12));
frequencyFactor.put("Yearly", new BigDecimal(1.0/12));
frequencyFactor.put("Quaterly", new BigDecimal(1.0/4));
frequencyFactor.put("Semiannually", new BigDecimal(1.0/6));

amountByFrequency.replaceAll((k,v) -> v .multiply(frequencyFactor.get(k)));
BigDecimal sum = amountByFrequency.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add ).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
System.out.println(amountByFrequency);
```

Comment: If you're worried about precision, I think you shouldn't use the [`new BigDecimal(Double d)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)) constructor while creating your `Map`, but rather `BigDecimal.ONE.divide(new BigDecimal(factor))`.

Comment: Also, `map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue)` can be shortened into `map.values().stream()`